# Check datagrid cell for value, if value is X change color of row

Tags: wpf, ironpython

I have a datagrid filled with data exported directly from SQL. In this grid I have a cell "Completed" with is a Boolean of True/False.

I want to parse over all rows in the datagrid check the value of the Completed cell and then change the color of the entire row to Green.

I have already written the code to access the specific column I am working with;

```
    self.rowColor()

def rowColor(self):
    try:
        for i in range(0, self.maindataGrid.Items.Count - 1):
            if self.maindataGrid.ItemsSource[i][13] == True:
                print(1)
    except IndexError:
        print('Index error at %i' % i)
```

This returns a print of 1 successfully for all the data I am parsing. How would I update the color of the row in XAML utilizing IronPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this.

I updated my XAML to specify bindings to specific columns returned via SQL then set a color accordingly.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="maindataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WHATSTAGE}" Value="C">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WHATSTAGE}" Value="B">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```